# check if a multiple id's exist in database

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have data in form of something like this ids =  [1,2,3,4] and I want to check if in database data exist except these id's then that data should be deleted .

querying for multiple id's like this but don't know how I can delete data if there is data exist except these id's in database

```
query = MyModel.query.filter(id.in_(ids)).all()
```

**EDIT**

this is exactly what I need

```
devices = session.query(Model).filter_by(~Model.device_uuid.in_(devices_list), draft_id=draft.id).delete()
```

but I am getting error that

**filter_by() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**

Answer (score 0):

In your .all(), what you get in return is not a query, but rows of data, each as an orm. You can delete the orms from the database session.

Otherwise, instead of using .all(), you can just .delete(), and that should delete the queried results from database.

Remember to call .commit() on your database session after deleting.

Comment: hi my query is not working  devices = session.query(Model).filter_by(~Model.device_uuid.in_(devices_list), draft_id=draft.id).delete()

Comment: You have to chain filter() calls, instead of adding many variable to 1 call.
Example: 
   WRONG .filter(a=1, b=2)
   CORRECT: .filter(a=1).filter(b=2)

Comment: getting this   'BinaryExpression' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'delete'